# Error when updating my new Ubuntu 12.04 LTS laptop

Tags: 12.04, kernel, updates, atheros

I have just bought a dell inspiron 3537 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS pre-installed.

However, update manager cannot successfully finish the initial update.

Here's part of the log at http://paste.ubuntu.com/7478635/  . Is there any hope????

Answer (score 0):

This could be worth a try and it is probably best to try before allowing the laptop to shutdown/reboot

Start by shutting down the update manager then open a terminal with ctrl-alt-t or searching for it in the dash.

Then run:

`sudo killall dpkg`

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Then try again with

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`